# Spring Boot JPA OneToOne relationship: how to force insert both entities upon save?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have created a OneToOne relationship as in the post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/536102/494659

Similarly we have two entities: `Invoice` & `InvoiceSequence` which is basically a sequence for it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices", indexes = {...})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice")
    private InvoiceSequence invoiceSequence;

    ...
}
```

and the InvoiceSequence entity:

```
@Entity
public class InvoiceSequence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long seqId;

    @OneToOne
    private Invoice invoice;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                .append("seqId", seqId)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

But when we save the Invoice, InvoiceSequence is saved as null. 
Example, in my unit test;

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setFleetId("F0001");
    invoice.setInvoicesStatus(InvoicesStatus.PENDING);
    invoice.setPricingId("1V1");
    invoice.setInvoiceDate(Date.from(toInstant));
    invoice.setTripId("000011111");
    invoice.setServiceId("001111");
    invoice.setUserId("1");
    invoice.setAmount(new BigDecimal("56"));
    invoiceService.save(invoice);
```

when i debug and look in the (in memory, H2) db, i see that the invoiceSequence is null.

The problem is very simple : *How can I make sure we have an incremented InvoiceSequence in long value when we insert a new Invoice*?

but I cannot get it work, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: As you have a  bi-directional relationship you have to make sure you set both fields. You probably only set the `InvoiceSequence` on the `Invoice` but not the other way around.

Comment: Can you share the method that you use to insert Invoice and how you populate the `Invoice` and `InvoiceSequence` variables ?

Comment: @Zeromus i ve removed the annotations that might be irrelevant..

Comment: @Al-MustafaAzhari i m testing via unit tests against h2 db.. i wonder if it would be different with a real mysql.

Comment: Did you create InvoiceSequence object and set in Invoice object?

Comment: @ShaikElias No. But thanks, indeed that s practically my question: i d like it to be done automagically by hibernate/jpa. is it possible?

Comment: Try to set empty object of `InvoiceSequence` to invoice , like  `invoice.setInvoiceSequence(new InvoiceSequence());` before call the `invoiceService.save(invoice);` mehtod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a wrong way of implementing a sequence. Why don't you have another field in `Invoice` like `sequence` and generate it using something like this:

[Multiple Hibernate sequence generators for one entity with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528450/multiple-hibernate-sequence-generators-for-one-entity-with-postgresql/34530385)

Also, if you really want to do it the way you suggested you need to manually create `InvoiceSequence` and then set it to `Invoice` before saving. You also need to set the `Invoice` to `InvoiceSequence` as described here:

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-one-mapping-example/

Comment: thanks! we are using MariaDb but i know we can do the same as in option#1. I went for option#2.