# How generate two sequence in one table hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I use spring boot/jpa/hibernate/MYSQL to generate schema and have table orders. I want generate 2 sequence in one table. First generated second ignored. How I could achieve that?

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_number")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long orderNumber;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Hibernate sequence generators for one entity with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528450/multiple-hibernate-sequence-generators-for-one-entity-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

The *implementation* of `@GeneratedValue` with the `AUTO` strategy in your actual SQL database will likely be to use an auto increment column.  Most databases do not even allow having two auto increment columns, and in general, there should not be a need why you even would need this.  I suggest just deleting one of either the `id` or `orderNumber` fields, and keeping the other one as the only auto increment column in your entity/table.

Comment: I want generate second sequence "order_number" to use it in other place as order number. When I add Order I could add UUID but it too long(useless). It will be good if it generated like  this 000001.

Comment: @TogrulSadigov Then add a computed column which formats the auto increment value the way you want to see it.